# How to use a ForeignKey field as filter in Django?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-views

I have 2 models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ### other fields

class Album(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ### other fields...
```

.

I just wrote a view for filtering albums by specefic category, also I want them all in home.html template:

```
#views.py
def commercial(request):
    commercial_subjects = Album.objects.filter(category__title__contains="commercial" )
    return render(request, 'gallery/index.html', {'commercial_subjects': commercial_subjects})
```

And it works fine for just commercial category. It seems just like hardcoding if I want to write multiple views for each category like this one. What I need is a view or filtering process which shows all categories and their related album.subject automaticly. So the final result must be like this:

> Personal
>
> - ALBUM 1
> - ALBUM 2
>
> Commercial
>
> - ALBUM 4
> - ALBUM5

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy. First of all give a [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to the foreign key:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='albums')
```

From view pass all categories:

```
def myView(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'gallery/index.html', {'categories': categories})
```

Then in template:

```
<ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
        {% with category.albums.all as albums %}
            {% if albums %}
                <ul>
                   {% for album in albums %}
                      <li>{{ album.subject }}</li>
                   {% endfor %}
                 <ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#views.py
def commercial(request):
    commercial_subjects = Album.objects.filter(category__title="commercial")
```

Comment: This is just what I said. I want sth to list all categories and related albums, not just list albums related to commercial category.